# Как передать state из одного компонента в другой

Tags: reactjs

есть 2 файла.
1

```
const FilterMobile = (tokensCount) => {
  return (
    <div className="class1">
      <Button
        onClick={() => this.setState({ filtersModalState: true })}
      >
      </Button>
    </div>
  )
}
export default FilterMobile
```

2 Собственно, вызов

```
<FilterMobile tokensCount={tokensCount} />
```

как передать стейт из 2 файла в 1? Ошибка Stateless functional components should not use 'this'

Answer (score 2):

В общем решил проблему, если кому пригодится:

```
const FilterMobile = ({ openFiltersModal, currentFilters }) => {
  return (
    <div className="class1">
      <Button
        onClick={() => openFiltersModal()}
      >
        )}
      </Button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Вызов соответственно

```
            <FilterMobile
              currentFilters={currentFilters}
              openFiltersModal={() =>
                this.setState({ filtersModalState: true })
              }
            />
```

Comment: Костыльный и непонятный выход. Для чего вы используете контекст в функциональном компоненте? Или же компонент, в котором находится FilterMobile является классом? Тогда нужно было сразу уточнить.

Answer (score 0):

Ну так вы почти правильно всё делаете. Я про сам метод передачи в другой компонент.
А вот проблема у вас сейчас в том, что вы пытаетесь использовать обычный функциональный компонент, как классовый. Определитесь, какой он должен быть: классовый или функциональный?
Если всё-таки функциональный, то просто вызовите функцию при клике (например), но не используйте this.setState (это установка стейта в классовом компоненте)
как-то так: `onClick={() => tokensCount()}`

Если компонент, должен стать классовым, то его нужно переписать иначе: унаследовать React.Component, добавить метод render и т.д.

Вот как можно использовать то, о чем я писал выше:

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  let tokensCount = () => {
    setCount(count + 1)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
     count: {count}
      <FilterMobile tokensCount = {tokensCount}/>
    </div>
  );
}

const FilterMobile = ({tokensCount}) => {
  return (
    <div className="class1">
      <button
        onClick={() => tokensCount()}
      >
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this.setState используется в классовых компонентах. Для хранения состояния в функциональных - используйте хук [useState](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) (здесь так же описаны отличия от классовых).

Итоговое решение такого:

```
const FilterMobile = (props) => {

  // tokensCount придет сюда. Обратиться к нему можно через props.tokensCount
  // либо же сразу деструктуризировать пропсы 
  // const FilterMobile = ({ tokensCount}) => { .... }

  const [filtersModal, setFiltersModal] = useState(false) // Зададим как false изначально

  return (
    <div className="class1">
      <Button
        onClick={() => setFiltersModal(true)}
      >
      </Button>
    </div>
  )
}
export default FilterMobile
```

Вызов будет таков:

```
<FilterMobile tokensCount={tokensCount} /> 
// где tokensCount - какое-то значение, которые мы 
// передаем через props в FilterMobile.
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как мне передать новое значение стейт в другой файл? Ошибка filtersModal is assigned a value but never used.